# How to make a ripple effect across a javascript canvas tilemap?

Tags: javascript, html

TLDR: How to make a diagonal line across a tile map that creates a ripple color effect

I have a tile map, like a 20x20 tile map, drawn with a Javascript Canvas. I want to make a ripple effect (Squares from top left corner to bottom right corner slowly change color by diagonal line). The problem is, my tile map is represented like so:

```
[
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
]
```

I have no clue where to begin, and how to slowly change the color with a diagonal line when the array is set up like so. I can access each individual square and I already have a for loop to change each color individually, any clue how to do this?

This is my for loop in case you wanted to see it:

```
//function to visualise the tile map in a 5x5 square around the player
function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
//start of row (y) 0 and column 0 (x)
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
    x++;
//if we are above the gridSize (20), reset column to 0
    if (i % gridSize == 0) {
      x = 0;
    }
//if we are above gridSize (20), and we are not on row 0, increment the row
    if (i % gridSize == 0 && i > 0) {
      y++;
    }

//Color each square accordingly
    if (grid[y][x] == "Obstacle") {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    }
    if (grid[y][x] == "Goal") {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    }
    if (grid[y][x] == "Empty") {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    }
    if (grid[y][x] == "Player") {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    }
    if (grid[y][x] == "Start") {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
    }
    if (grid[y][x] == "Valid" || grid[y][x] == "Invalid" || grid[y][x] == "Visited") {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    }

//Draw each square so that is is 400/gridSize (400/20 or 20) wide and the same height.
    ctx.fillRect((x) * 400 / gridSize, (y) * 400 / gridSize, 400 / gridSize, 400 / gridSize)
    ctx.beginPath();

//You can ignore this, it just makes borders for each tile
    ctx.rect((x) * 400 / gridSize - 1, (y) * 400 / gridSize - 1, 400 / gridSize + 2, 400 / gridSize + 2)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
```

TLDR: How to make a diagonal line across a tile map that creates a ripple color effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution, if anybody really cares. all i had to do was make an array containing every position in order then draw those in order. An example is the function floodMoves() in this JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6muLzn70/3/

the code is simply:

```
let arr = moveList[count2].split(",");
    x2 = Number(arr[0]);
    y2 = Number(arr[1]);
    if (count2 >= moveList.length - 1) {
      grid[y2][x2] = "Flood";
      clearInterval(int2)
    } else {
      grid[y2][x2] = "Flood";
    }
```

all wrapped in an interval. All this does is visualize a ripple effect utilizing the deapth-first algorithm, which can be found here: http://gregtrowbridge.com/a-basic-pathfinding-algorithm/